# How to use .each to build an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So we're working in this system and buildig our own page. We built a form to insert timeline data using a .xwd file. We use javascript to retrieve the data and fill it in a variable to store it. The main page (`title:`) just has single values, but the actual events should be in an array.

I'm want to use V to fill the array.

```
$(x_currentPageXML).children().each(function(index, elem){

});
```

Right now what I have is this and I want to fill the "events" array using the foreach I showed above. Putting the `.each` inside in the var didn't work and I wouldn't know how else to do it.

```
    var SictTimeline = new function() {     
            this.loadJS = function () {
        $.getScript(x_templateLocation + 'common_html5/js/timeline.js')
            .done(function (script, textStatus) {
                var make_the_json = $(x_currentPageXML).children().map(function (element) {
                    return {
                        title: {
                            media: {
                                url: element.getAttribute("url"),
                                caption: element.getAttribute("tip"),
                            },
                            text: {
                                headline: element.getAttribute("name"),
                                text: '<p>' + element.getAttribute("text") + '</p>'
                            }
                        },
                        events: {
                            media: {
                                url: element.getAttribute("url"),
                                caption: element.getAttribute("tip"),
                            },
                            start_date: {
                                month: '8',
                                day: '9',
                                year: '1963'
                            },
                            text: {
                                headline: element.getAttribute("name"),
                                text: element.getAttribute("text")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

                var timeline_json = make_the_json; // replace make_the_json() with the JSON object you created
                // two arguments: the id of the Timeline container (no '#')
                // and the JSON object or an instance of TL.TimelineConfig created from
                // a suitable JSON object
                window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', timeline_json);
            })
            .fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                console.log('Failed to load the script for the timeline');
            });
    }
    // function called every time the page is viewed after it has initially loaded
    this.pageChanged = function() {

    }

    // function called every time the size of the LO is changed
    this.sizeChanged = function() {

    }

    this.init = function() {
        this.loadJS();
        // call this function in every model once everything's loaded
        x_pageLoaded();
    }
}
```

An example of the xml-file with the values

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<learningObject editorVersion="3" targetFolder="Nottingham" name="Learning Object Title" language="en-GB" navigation="Linear" textSize="12" theme="default" displayMode="fill window" responsive="true">

<SictTimeline linkID="PG1592486441661" name="My page" media="SictTimeline" text="&lt;p&gt;Text for my page&lt;/p&gt;&#10;" url="FileLocation + 'media/https___images.genius.com_53c4575fa3f97a8d4b18d69a600afaf0.900x900x1.jpg'" tip="Description for Image 1"></SictTimeline></learningObject>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to achieve is to generate an array of objects based on the number (and properties) of elements inside `$(x_currentPageXML)`. For that purpose you need to use the [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method:

```
    events: $(x_currentPageXML).children().map(function (index, element) {
        return {
            media: {
                url: element.getAttribute("url"),
                caption: element.getAttribute("tip"),
            },
            start_date: {
                month: '8',
                day: '9',
                year: '1963'
            },
            text: {
                headline: element.getAttribute("name"),
                text: element.getAttribute("text")
            }
        }
    }).get()
```

Comment: I've tried it but it hasn't worked sadly. I've edited the code, added also what was behind it. maybe it can help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the contents of `x_currentPageXML`?

Comment: It's an xml-file with the values of the input.

Comment: I've added the data from the xml-file, the attributes in `<SictTimeline>` are the ones getting retrieved by the `getAttribute` and are the ones I need in the `events` array. Only `events` should be in the `.map` I think, that one will have multiple objects. `titles` shouldn't, there's only 1 of those.

Comment: Actually I see why you were not getting the object. I forgot to add the index to the callback and to get the resulting object adding `.get()` at the end of `.map()`. See this example I've created and tell me if it worked https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-smoke-h3ztb?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Wait its starting to do something now, but it's a bit buggy, I'm going to check it out and I'll let you know the status, thank you very much though

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but you want to extract stuff from each element in the loop right?
Replace `x_currentPageXML` with `elem` inside the loop

```
var result = []

$(x_currentPageXML).children().each(function (index, elem) {
    var make_the_json = {
        title: {
            media: {
                url: elem.getAttribute("url"),
                caption: elem.getAttribute("tip"),
            },
            text: {
                headline: elem.getAttribute("name"),
                text: '<p>' + elem.getAttribute("text") + '</p>'
            }
        },
        events: [
            {
                media: {
                    url: elem.getAttribute("url"),
                    caption: elem.getAttribute("tip"),
                },
                start_date: {
                    month: '8',
                    day: '9',
                    year: '1963'
                },
                text: {
                    headline: elem.getAttribute("name"),
                    text: elem.getAttribute("text")
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    result.push(make_the_json)
})
```

Comment: I've edited the code, added also what was behind it. maybe it can help.